# you've reached the limit for text post on Windows Phone - tumblr

Tags: apps, error

I was using tumblr app on my wPhone, while i was heading to post a new quote, i started writing some text, and this appeared. I though it must be restriction for a day, but it has been over 3 days. This problem is happening only on my wPhone and only when i try to post some quote, not with any other type of post.

[image: The error]

Comment: The tumblr app is long outdated. Have you tried another app to see what happens?

Comment: nope, but i tried using tumblr on my browser and it didn't show any error.

Comment: Man, Tumblr's dev team should work.

Comment: It looks as if you're using Windows 10 Mobile. If so, I'd recommend something like Ouga.

Comment: yup, it's windows 10. Can that be a problem?

Comment: I doubt it. The app is just really outdated. I'd try Ouga and see if that helps.

Comment: i will try ouga too then. But, still this type of problem with the official Tumblr app can be a serious problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are rate limits in place for Tumblr apps so a work-around is to use the website or a third-party app until the limit is lifted.